# TextInputLayout remove unwanted space

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml, android-textinputlayout

I want TextInputLayout without any border and box, so I use below code for

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/app_name"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

but i don't know when I write

> app:boxBackgroundMode="none"

to TextInputLayout then size is an automatic stretch and looks so weird if you find any solution regarding this plz help me.

Here is the screenshot of my output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"`

try following code to achieve your design

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="@string/app_name">

    <EditText
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```